# AngularJS: How to create and use an array for a value in the HTML

Tags: angularjs, html

I have created a custom directive with fields: `ng-model`, `input-array`

```
<mydir ng-model="myBinding" input-array="input1,input2"></mydir>
```

Input 1 and input 2 are both data bindings, how can I dynamically create an array of these two and pass then in the `input-array` argument?

I do not want this logic to be in a controller or the directive.

Comment: Can you show us your directive code? Also your attributes can take an object or an array not the comma separated arguments

Comment: Check that besides adding braces to the array you must also properly close the `mydir` directive: `<mydir ng-model="myBinding" input-array="[input1, input2]"></mydir>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap the variables in array braces

```
input-array="[input1,input2]"
```

Beyond that there isn't nearly enough detail in question

Comment: Do you know how I can use the subtr() function on input1 and input2?

Comment: what is `subtr()` ?

Comment: to do what exactly? One thing you need to learn here when asking questions is to provide proper context details of what you are trying to accomplish